# Parse File using flex and bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, text-parsing, fileparsing

I need to parse following file using flex and Bison:

new file

```
BEGIN BLOCK BLK_ROWDEC  
            NAME                          cell_rowdec  
            SIZE                             UNI_rowdecSize  
            ITERATE                                   itr_rows  
            DIRECTION                               lgDir_rowdec  
            STRAP                         STRD1,STRD3,STRD2  
            WRAP                          WRD1  
            VIA                                           VIAB,VIAC,VIAD  
 ENDS BLK_ROWDEC
```

I want to read above file and for that I write this code

lex.l

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "yacc.tab.h"
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()

using namespace std;
%}

DOT             "."
COLON           ":"
SEMICOLON       ";"
COMMA           ","
ANGLE_LEFT      "<"
ANGLE_RIGHT     ">"
AT              "@"
EQUAL           "="
SQUARE_OPEN     "["
SQUARE_CLOSE    [^\\]"]"
OPENBRACE       "\("
CLOSEBRACE      "\)"
QUOTE           "\""
QUOTE_OPEN      "\""
QUOTE_CLOSE     [^\\]"\""
SPACE           " "
TAB             "\t"
CRLF            "\r\n"
QUOTED_PAIR     "\\"[^\r\n]
DIGIT           [0-9]
ALPHA           [a-zA-Z]
QTEXT           [0-9a-zA-Z!#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]

%%

[a-zA-Z0-9]+            { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return TOK_STRING; }

{SPACE}*                    {return TOK_SPACE; }

^{SPACE}*Name            {return TOK_NAME; }
{SPACE}*SIZE.*              {return TOK_SIZE; }
{SPACE}*ITERATE.*           {return TOK_ITERATE; }
{SPACE}*DIRECTION.*     {return TOK_DIRECTION; }

^{CRLF}                         { return TOK_EMPTY_LINE; }
 {CRLF}                          {}
 .                               {}/* ignore unknown chars */
```

yacc.y

```
%{
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex();
extern "C" FILE *yyin;

void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

// Symbols.
%union
{
    char* sval;
};

%token <sval> TOK_NAME
%token <sval> TOK_SIZE
%token <sval> TOK_STRING
%token <sval> TOK_ITERATE
%token <sval> TOK_DIRECTION
%token <sval> TOK_EMPTY_LINE 
%token TOK_SPACE


%%

str:
    TOK_SPACE TOK_NAME TOK_SPACE TOK_STRING 
    {
        cout << "Value:" << $2 << "->" << $4;
    }
    ;
%%

int main(void) {
    FILE * pt = fopen("new file ", "r" );
    if(!pt)
    {
    cout << "Bad Input.Noexistant file" << endl;
    return -1;
    }
    yyin = pt;
    do
    {
        yyparse();
    }while (!feof(yyin));      
}
void yyerror(const char *s)
{
   cout << "Error. " << s << endl; 
   exit(-1);   
}
#include "lex.yy.c"
```

First, I just try to print second line of file but I am not able to print anything. Please help me what could I do??

Compilation is done by:

```
flex lex.l
bison -d yacc.y
g++ yacc.tab.c -lfl -o scanner.exe
```

Comment: bison/flex parsers work sequentially from the beginning of the input to the end. They don't skip through the input looking for something that they might be able to match.

Comment: but why it didn't print anything??what is problem with my script??

Comment: please help me @rici

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very important knowing how to debug your parser. In first part of the file, `#define YYDEBUG 1`, and in main set `yydebug = 1`. This will allow you to see exact steps when you run your parser ant then you'll know where your error is. Knowing this is extrimely important, because mistakes are very hard to find. So debug your program!

```
%{
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define YYDEBUG 1 // This is new

using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex();
extern "C" FILE *yyin;

void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

int main(){

  yydebug = 1; // This is new
  yyparse();
}
```

Also `yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);` after this you need to check whether yylval.sval is NULL, because `strdup(yytext)` is first allocating memory, and after that function is copying string, so `strdup(yytext)` will return NULL if memory allocation fails.

Comment: I add this both statement but it didn't work. I didn't get any outputs. please help me ..Its urgent

Comment: You need to do `yacc -d` command first because `yacc` is generating `.h` file for `lex`.  That file is saying to Lex what tokens are. And after that you need to do flex.  Also your compilation process at the end is wrong, you need to compile `yacc` file to object file, `lex` file to object file, and after that merge them into one executable.

Comment: If you don't understand the word of what I just said, please read flex's and yacc's documentation, or watch some tutorial.

Comment: when I debug my code I found following lines:  Starting parse  
Entering state 0  
Reading a token: Next token is token TOK_STRING ()  
Error. syntax error

Comment: For god sake, in debug mode enter token after token and you'll find your error. For example: 1 enter 2 enter 3 enter etc. That way you'll find where your error is.